# Please let me post an improved question

Tags: discussion

I first posted a question regarding some cricket terminology. Then, I got back new info from my teacher according to which I now need to update the question.

This is the older question I posted: [Overthrow and throw-by](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17358/overthrow-and-throw-by)

This is the new question: [What exactly is a throw-by?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17362/what-exactly-is-a-throw-by)

Now, **I want to do one of the following things**:

1. Copy the question body from new post into old post and delete the new post.
2. Delete the old post and migrate answer from old post into new post.

And accordingly ask the user who posted one answer to modify his answer.

The newer question better achieves what I was trying to ask. Please let me do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just done (1) for you; nothing was stopping you doing this yourself. [I rolled back your changes to the first question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/17358/revisions) not because of any minor changes in the wording, but because you started asking an entirely separate question about naming an event, rather than the meaning of a term.

Comment: Understood. Thanks ^_^